# Community promotion advert for Stack Exchange search

Tags: discussion, design

One of the things I stumbled across recently after a long time was the 'search all stack exchange' page on Stack Exchange.  I've been looking over that little grey 'search all sites' in the upper right corner of the page thinking it was searching *sites*, not posts at sites. [The search page](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=) - yea, bet you didn't know it did do things like [big o gcd](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=big+o+gcd) nicely (there's stack overflow, programmers, math, math overflow, cs... pages upon pages of answers!)

So, I was thinking about making a community advertisement for this page to show up in our regular rotation of adverts.  On Programmers.SE, we all too often get people asking questions that already were asked on Stack Overflow in days of old.  Hinting that there's a "search everywhere" and that it is a *good* thing to search first might avoid some of these "is an implementation question, but would be closed as a dup on Stack Overflow of ..." close reasons.

The thing is, between my... lets call them utilitarian graphic design skills <del>and fondness of pie charts</del> I'm a bit hesitant to make a go of it on my own, especially lacking a [good style guide](http://thestandardsmanual.com/page.html#1) to make it look professional.

If someone would point me in the direction of a proper style guide for Stack Exchange logo, fonts, and the like, I'd be happy to make a go of it on my own.  If someone wants to make *make* an image that would save me from embarrassing myself with my drawing skills, I'd be even more happy (you know, the [standard](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/community-promotion-ads-2014) 220 x 250 pixels, png or gif (but not animated), no larger than 150 kb) to put it in the community adverts.

P.S. If this is a good idea, maybe SE could come up with one and use it as a second prototype advert when 2015 rolls around so it looks all nice and official and stuff.